# how to add nofollow to menu in jem.jrox theme?

Tags: php, html, seo, nofollow

I need to No-Follow these links in www.drstanleys.com .

[image: menu]

I have edited the tpl_header.php file and added the following code.

```
<div id="jroxViewCart" class="jroxViewCart"><a rel="nofollow" href="{base_url}cart">{cart_items}</a></div>

<div id="jroxTopLinks" class="jroxTopLinks">

    <span id="jroxTopHomePage"><a href="{public_url}" rel="nofollow">{lang_home} </a></span>

    {if {mlogin} == 1}

    <span id="jroxTopMyAccount"><a href="{members_login_url}{members_route}" rel="nofollow">{lang_my_account}</a></span> 

    <span id="jroxTopLogout"><a href="{base_url}logout" rel="nofollow">{lang_logout}</a></span> 

    {else}

    <span id="jroxTopLogin"><a href="{members_login_url_link}login" rel="nofollow">{lang_login}</a></span> 

    <span id="jroxTopRegister"><a href="{checkout_url_link}registration" rel="nofollow">{lang_register}</a></span> 

    {/if}

    <span id="jroxTopCheckout"><a href="{base_url}cart" rel="nofollow">{lang_checkout}</a></span>

</div>
```

Still it is not changing.I am not That good in codeignitor coding.someone please help in solving this.Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you made it. All links at the header are nofollow but i do not recommend to you add nofollow tag to homepage url.

```
    <div id="jroxViewCart" class="jroxViewCart"><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.drstanleys.com/cart">no items in your cart</a></div>
<div id="jroxTopLinks" class="jroxTopLinks">
    <span id="jroxTopHomePage"><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.drstanleys.com/">home</a></span> 

    <span id="jroxTopLogin"><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.drstanleys.com/login">login</a></span> 
    <span id="jroxTopRegister"><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.drstanleys.com/registration">register</a></span> 

    <span id="jroxTopCheckout"><a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.drstanleys.com/cart">checkout</a></span>
```

Comment: yes.I have made it.thanks for the reply.and yeah will dofollow home page link.thanks!